# HTML parse error: Service out of order - when trying parsing a website

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, screen-scraping

i want to parse a website but
i always get an Error: service out of order.

No matter what start or end string i give.
I also tried to use an other URL and i copied
full examples from other users that works for them
but not for me. I also tried to increase the Size to 20000.
But nothing is working.

Here is my php-Script:

```
<?php
// URL, die durchsucht werden soll
$url = "http://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/85400_en.html";

// Zeichenfolge vor relevanten Einträgen
$startstring = "<div class='tech'><p>";

// bis zum nächsten html tag bzw. Zeichenfolge nach relevanten Einträgen
$endstring = "<"; 

$file = @fopen ($url,"r");

if($file)
{
    echo "URL found<br>";
}

if (trim($file) == "") {
    echo "Service out of order - File:".$file."<br>";
    } else {
    $i=0;
    while (!feof($file)) {

        // Wenn das File entsprechend groß ist, kann es unter Umständen
        // notwendig sein, die Zahl 2000 entsprechend zu erhöhen. Im Falle
        // eines Buffer-Overflows gibt PHP eine entsprechende Fehlermeldung aus.

        $zeile[$i] = fgets($file,20000);
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($file);
}

// Data filtering

for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
    if ($resa = strstr($zeile[$j],$startstring)) {
        $resb = str_replace($startstring, "", $resa);
        $endstueck = strstr($resb, $endstring);
        $resultat .= str_replace($endstueck,"",$resb);
        $resultat .= "; ";
    }
}

// Data output

echo ("Result = ".$resultat."<br>");
return $resultat;
```

Any help is appreciate.
thanks in advance

EDIT: The URL is found and file has a value: Resource id #3

Comment: What data you want from website??

Comment: i just want simple text. its like a description on the website. its under Objective if you look at the page

Comment: $file is a file handle. What do you want to check with trim($file)? This will always be empty.

Comment: just check the below program it will give you output as expected.

Comment: @ChristianMansch have you check program

Comment: @ChristianMansch if you like answer just make up vote... -Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this it will give expected output.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/85400_en.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); 

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
$headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Cookie:CORDIS=14.141.177.158.1441621012200552; PHPSESSID=jrf2e3t4vu56acdkf9np0tat06; WT_FPC=id=14.141.177.158-1441621016.978424:lv=1441605951963:ss=1441604805004
Host:cordis.europa.eu';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Host:cordis.europa.eu';
$headers[] = 'Request URL:http://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/85400_en.html';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($server_output);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$div = $xpath->query("//*[@class='tech']")->item(0);
$data = trim($div->textContent);
echo $data;
?>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<?php
// URL, die durchsucht werden soll
$url = "http://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/85400_en.html";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

if ($html === false) {
    //Service unavailable
    echo 'Service unavailable';
    return;
}
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$div = $xpath->query("//*[@class='tech']")->item(0);
$output = trim($div->textContent);

// Data output

echo ("Result = " . $output. "<br>");
return $output;
```

Comment: return $resultat; is blank

Comment: The server is overloaded now ;-)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, that is exactly what i needed. Both solutions work for me. Thank for your effort